# Checkbox attribute not getting set on click

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

Anyone ever seen anything like this before? It's driving me mad! Basically, I've got a checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='eventRepeat' />
```

...and some jQuery, which I've now stripped down to:

```
$('#eventRepeat').click( function() { alert($(this).attr('checked')) })
```

...but it alerts 'checked' whether it is checked or not when I click it! Weird. I've checked the DOM to see if there is another rogue `eventRepeat;` element, but there isn't, and the HTML validates, give or take a warning or two (*no errors*)

Other checkboxes on the same page work fine! All ideas welcome!

Comment: Cheers - both of those work. Now, where am I using 'attr' in all my code :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try -

```
$('#eventRepeat').click( function() { alert($(this).prop('checked')) })
```

`prop` should give a truer representation of the state of the checkbox than the `attr` function. See the docs - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `:checked` selector:

```
$('#eventRepeat').click( function(){ 
    alert($(this).is(":checked")) 
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Es6Z/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/UGPyT/ it seems to work ^^